# What will happen if build exe launch from Visual Studio without guna ui activation?

Tags: visual-studio, exe, activation

I'm using Guna UI2 to design my application on Visual Studio 2022. On every time that I open Visual Studio, Guna UI2's activation required window is pop out, but if I turn it off I can still use Guna component to design as normal. What will happen if I build my app to an exe launcher without activating Guna? All buttons from Guna is disable?

Comment: Hope someone helps me, i really need solution for this

Comment: What's so complicated to answer your questions yourself? Just build the exe, and you will see what happens. As I understand, Guna UI is a paid component. If you don't have purchased the license, it will surely display some messages during runtime. But this is something you should ask their support, not here.

Comment: See https://gunaui.com/faq/. You cannot distribute the application without a valid license, and after 14-day trial period, you will not be able to edit your project.